# Loading a grid in xaml code from a file, then making it active in main code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, resources

I am making a video game, where each grid serves as game room. Each grid\room has a large number of objects like things that can be used, images and sound files. Until now, they all were stored in one large file. But now, I was told that this approach wastes a lot of resources.

My plan is, to store xaml code of every such grid as a separate file, then load relevant file at run time with usual code.

For now xaml looks about like this:

```
    <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"            
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"   
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="wdwMain" x:Class="RealityIncognita.MainWindow"
    Height="900" Width="1600" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" 
    Cursor="Cross" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="wdwMain_Loaded">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid x:Name="areaContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="900" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1600">
        <Grid x:Name="areaMain">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush  
    ImageSource="Resources/Images/Interface/main_interface.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>
    <Grid x:Name="areaShowers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="700"  
    Margin="1653,790,-1561,-590" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1508"   
    IsVisibleChanged="areaShowers_IsVisibleChanged">
```

Here's example - areaShowers is a grid for relevant room. Until now, it was stored in the main file, like all other grids, and when I needed, I just altered its Margin to put it upon "areaMain" - also a grid.

Now though, I want to put each room into a file, then load it when I need it, and remove it from memory when I don't.

For example I'll create an empty grid "areaGeneric" and add it and it alone to original xaml.

So, I want something like this. Can't provide any earlier attempt, because I don't really know how it can be done.

```
Grid new_grid = new Grid;
new_grid = load from file (areaRoom.xaml); (file is among the project's 
resources)
areaGeneric = new_grid;
```

Can I load a grid xaml at run-time, then switch grids in main code?

Thank you,
Evgenie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution would just be to house each of your rooms inside a user control and then place the control into your container grid when you need to change rooms. Here's the rough idea:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    UserControl _currentRoom;  

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         this.areaContainer.Children.Clear();
         _currentRoom = null;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            _currentRoom = new Room1(); 
        if(e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) 
            _currentRoom = new Room2(); 

        this.areaContainer.Children.Add(_currentRoom); 
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }

}
```

A "Room":

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Room1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Button Height="100" Width="100">
        Hello world!
    </Button>   
</UserControl>
```

As for cleaning up your resources - once the user control is removed from the visual tree (assuming you aren't holding a reference) the GC should dispose of the user control. If you wanted to clear your resources more quickly you could  implement a dispose method on your rooms and then call that before you change areas.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem. The interior images\buttons\voids from relevant grid don't work. "'RealityIncognita.Room' does not contain a definition for 'objHibernation1Pod4_MouseEnter' and no extension method 'objHibernation1Pod4_MouseEnter' accepting a first argument of type 'RealityIncognita.Room' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That particular error seems to be indicating that you are missing an event handler in your code behind for the user control that was probably on your main window before you started seperating out your rooms. You'll need to add handlers into your usercontrol. You might also need to update your references/paths relative to wherever your user control is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I have more questions. First - the idea was to avoid loading everything at once. Will such separating of grids really help in this issue? I mean, if I update all paths to new file? And second - can you give example or link how exactly I add handlers? Each grid has a lot of buttons and voids - will I need to connect them one by one?

Comment: Yes, it will avoid loading everything at once. When you switch to a new room by placing it into the "areaContaier" resources for that room (such as images) will be loaded only when you initialse it. 

Here's some documentation on adding event handlers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655886(v=vs.90).aspx  

Finally, I assumed it was just a case of moving the button handlers from your MainWindow to your usercontrol, but it's hard to say since I can't see your solution .If some buttons are part of a common game UI you might want to seperate those out to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I'll reply when I check if it works at evening.

Comment: I can't check it, too many things must be changed, but I think that this approach is correct, so marking as solved. Thank you.